# saber que boton se esta presionando en php

Tags: php, html, botón

tengo este código el cual contiene 3 botones, quiero saber cual de los 3 ha sido presionado

```
<form action="Examen.php" method="POST">
     <button><img src="Piedra.jpeg" width="150" height="150" /></button>
     <button><img src="papel.jpeg"  width="150" height="150" /></button>
     <button><img src="tijera.jpeg" width="150" height="150" /></button>
 </form>
```

quisiera saber hacer para que regrese un valor al ser presionado ya sea un true o un numero 1

Comment: Pues hasta donde se php no puede interactuar mucho con el usuario, pero en cambio javascript  y/o jquery si pueden, por lo que puedes mejor usarlos para devolver valores y ya desde ahí solo los recibes en php

Answer (score 0):

Agregale un value a tu button ejemplo

```
<button name="seleccionado" value="Pierdra.jpg"><img/></> 
<button name="seleccionado" value="papel.jpg"><img/></>
```

de esta forma cuando el formulario se envíe solo te enviará el boton que se seleccionó

Answer (score 0):

Otra posible solución es usar Javascript y usas una función

```
<form action="Examen.php" method="POST">
 <button><img onclick="cual('boton1')" src="Piedra.jpeg" width="150" height="150" /></button>
 <button><img onclick="cual('boton2')" src="papel.jpeg"  width="150" height="150" /></button>
 <button><img onclick="cual('boton3')" src="tijera.jpeg" width="150" height="150" /></button>
```

y JS

```
                function cual(id)
                {
                    console.log("Boton Seleccionado "+id);
                    //Puedes guardar esto en alguna variable y usarlo como desees
                }
```